# xfs_growfs: / is not a mounted XFS filesystem

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, vps

I have a Virtual Private Server and just upgraded the HDD space but am unable to extend my drive, at least I don't know how.

```
root@localhost:~# xfs_growfs /
xfs_growfs: / is not a mounted XFS filesystem
```

### Hardware

```
 *-scsi:0
      physical id: 87
      logical name: scsi2
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         product: Virtual disk
         vendor: VMware
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: 2.0
         serial: 6000c29d6dd9f71e6d153468cd60d2fb
         size: 160GiB (171GB)
         capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
         configuration: ansiversion=6 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=520f1760
       *-volume:0
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sda1
            logical name: /boot
            version: 1.0
            serial: de2cb53e-6086-4fd5-99a9-1c22674a4f91
            size: 487MiB
            capacity: 487MiB
            capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2021-05-20 11:12:55 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2022-01-05 19:12:46 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2022-01-05 18:58:01 state=mounted
       *-volume:1
            description: Linux LVM Physical Volume partition
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            serial: R5VWXg-jamB-5dWM-PpwY-7a49-LRz7-Vrvdl2
            size: 9751MiB
            capacity: 79GiB
            capabilities: primary multi lvm2

root@localhost:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 160 GiB, 171798691840 bytes, 335544320 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x520f1760

Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       999424 335544286 334544863 159.5G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv00: 1.93 GiB, 2046820352 bytes, 3997696 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-lv01: 77.63 GiB, 83336626176 bytes, 162766848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What confuses me here is that here it says it does have the 160gb `/dev/sda2       999424 335544286 334544863 159.5G 8e Linux LVM` but when I check its not there:

```
root@localhost:~# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                  794M  1.2M  793M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv01   77G   31G   43G  43% /
tmpfs                  3.9G   16K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                  3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1              456M  145M  278M  35% /boot
tmpfs                  794M     0  794M   0% /run/user/0
```

I am wondering if I need a server reboot?

Comment: Try rebooting, and see if it helps.

Comment: resetting it didn't help. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The partition type is **LVM** which means your root partition is a logical volume (LV). A logical volume belongs to a volume group (VG) which consists of one or more physical volumes (PV).
Try this:

```
vgdisplay -v
# Note the following values:
# PV Name, e. g. '/dev/vda3' (physical volume)
# LV Path, e. g. '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' (logical volume)

growpart <DISK> <PARTITION_NUMBER> # e.g. 'growpart /dev/vda 3'
pvresize <PV_NAME> # Resize the physical volume
lvresize <LV_NAME> -l 100%VG # Logical Volume should get the whole space of the Volume Group
resize2fs <LV_NAME> # Resize the file system (e. g. ext4)
```